# Haskell ['a'..'z'] for French

Tags: haskell

I wonder, if this

```
alph = ['a'..'z']
```

returns me

> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

How can I return French alphabet then? Can I pass somehow a locale?

**Update:**
Well ) I know that English and French has the same letters. But my point is if they were not the same but starts with A and ends with Z. Would be nice to have human language range support.

At least some languages come with localizations support.

(just trying Haskell, reading a book)

Comment: What do you mean by [French alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_alphabet)?  It's the same as the English alphabet (modulo pronunciation).  Do you want letters with diacritics and ligatures?

Comment: Programming languages don't recognize human alphabets. They recognize computer alphabets like ASCII and Unicode. In computer alphabets each character is assigned a code. For example `A..Z` ranges from `65..90` and `a..z` ranges from `97..122`. If you want characters which are not in the [Basic Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) character set then you would have to use the appropriate enumeration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haskell `Char` values are not real characters, they are Unicode code points. In some other languages their native character type may represent other things like ASCII characters or "code page whatsitsnumber" characters, or even something selectable at runtime, but not in Haskell.

The range `'a'..'z'` coincides with the English alphabet for historical reasons, both in Unicode and in ASCII, and also in character sets derived from ASCII such as ISO8859-X. There is no commonly supported coded character set where some contiguous range of codes coincides with the French alphabet. That is, if you count letters with diacritics as separate letters. The accepted practice seems to exclude letters with diacritics, so the French alphabet coincides with English, but this is not so for other Latin-derived alphabets.

In order to get most alphabets other than English, one needs to enumerate the characters explicitly by hand and not with any range expression. For some languages one even cannot use `Char` to represent all letters, as some of them need more than one code point, such as Hungarian "ly" or Spanish "ll" (before 2010) or Dutch "ij" (according to some authorities — there's no one commonly accepted definition).

No language that I know supports arbitrary human alphabets as range expressions out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

While programming languages usually support sorting by the current locale (just search for `collate` on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=collate)), there is no library I know that provides a list of alphabetic characters by locale.

Modern (Unicode) systems allowing for localized characters try to also allow many non-latin alphabets, and thus very many alphabetic characters.

Enumerating all alphabetic characters within Unicode gives over 40k characters:

```
GHCi> length $ filter Data.Char.isAlpha $
               map Data.Char.chr [0..256*256]
48408
```

While I am aware of [libraries allowing to construct alphabetic indices](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1AlphabeticIndex.html#details), I don't know about any Haskell binding for this feature.

Comment: To be fair, most of those 48408 are CJK ideographs, which are classified as "letters" but are not really alphabetic. BTW Unicode is not 256*256 code points, there are more :)